# Openbox: disable Alt-F4 on per application basis

Tags: openbox, lxde

I am using `LXDE` and in my `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` I have action for <kbd>ALT-F4</kbd> defined:

```
<keybind key="A-F4">
  <action name="Close"/>
</keybind>
```

This works, as expected, for all applications. When <kbd>ALT-F4</kbd> is pressed, the window is closed.

I have one application, lets call it `foo`, which I would like to be unaffected by <kbd>ALT-F4</kbd>. i.e. when <kbd>ALT-F4</kbd> is pressed, I want the window to stay open (the action should be completely ignored).

Is it possible to create such rule?

EDIT:
Based on the answer  from `@Michael Homer` I have added following into my `.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="A-F4">
  <action name="If">
    <title>foo</title>
    <then>
      <!-- Do nothing for foo -->
    </then>
    <else>
      <action name="Close"/>
    </else>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

This works great, but I would need to match `foo` or `bar`.

**What would be the simplest solution to achieve that?**

Comment: Not according to the manual - but I'm no expert (hence, comment not answer).

Comment: same problem, but i don't need to ..do nothing.., i need to do what do Escape button by default, what action is it? Thank you. xdotool key Escape didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with an [If action](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#If):

```
<keybind key="A-F4">
 <action name="If">
  <title>* foo</title>
  <then><!-- Do nothing for foo --></then>
  <else>
   <action name="Close" />
  </else>
 </action>
</keybind>
```

The `<title>` condition will match a window title ending " foo". There are variations `<title type="regex">` and `<title type="exact">` for other kinds of match. When the window matches, the action will do nothing, and when it doesn't (for every other window) it will close as usual.

[Openbox 3.6 and newer](http://openbox.org/wiki/Openbox:Changelog#3.6) include additional selector tags [`<class>`, `<name>`, and `<role>`](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#If) which can help to identify your window more precisely if the title isn't unique. They support the same `type` attribute and content as `<title>`, but are tested against the relevant X property instead.

---

If you're using an earlier version of Openbox and your window can't be identified by title, you're in less luck, but it's possible to hack something together with [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/): bind the A-F4 action to a script that identifies the window more precisely, and then send a secret key combination that's bound to the actual close action if it doesn't match.

Comment: my application has title set to `"None"`. But can I use other tags, such as `class` or `name` ?

Comment: That title is probably uncommon enough that you could use `<title type="exact">None</title>`, but otherwise there isn't anything built in for dealing with class. You could piece it together with xdotool at a pinch.

Comment: I know that, but it always looks like playing the wise guy with such minor typo fixes. :) I normally only do that with bigger issues: bad layout,. bad grouping etc.

Comment: @Michael Homer - is it possible to match `<title>* foo</title>` or `<title>* bar</title>`?

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: @Michael Homer - could you please advise  how?

Comment: If you have a new question you should [ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it so that other people will see it, rather than editing an old question nobody will look at.

Comment: @MartinVegter: As of Openbox 3.6 (released this week), you can use both `class` and `name` to match a window.