# How to create an X window which won't close by any way other than a terminal command

Tags: terminal, x11, openbox

I'm trying to create a process that will start with X11, will be graphical and unkillable by my own user.

More specifically, I have an urxvt drop-down terminal starting at startup and running a tmux session right away. What annoys me, is that I sometimes kill it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> when I forget that it is the drop-down terminal and I'm supposed to hide it instead.

Sure, I'm not losing my tmux session since I can reattach to it from another terminal, but I'd have to re-launch the drop-down terminal (with the exact config) and reattach and that's tedious.

What I would want to do, is to **not be able to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>  kill this specific process**.

After reading this:
[Make a process unkillable on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227459/make-a-process-unkillable-on-linux)

I understood that I should launch the process as belonging to another user, yet even if I manage to do that within my own X server with:

```bash
    sudo xhost +local:
    sudo runuser -l my-secondary-user -c urxvt
```

I face two unwanted behaviours:

1. The process is killable by my main user (the one who owns the X session).
2. The virtual terminal starts logged in as my-secondary-user (of course).

The (2) may be rectifiable - just run a command to login as my main user instead - but I have no idea on how to fix the (1).

Is there a way to make this work, or another way to do what I want? I'd rather avoid having to mess with creating kernel modules if possible.

Running Arch Linux with Openbox.

**EDIT**

I got thinking that I may be able to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> not work for this specific window.
found this:
[Openbox: disable Alt-F4 on per application basis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139907/openbox-disable-alt-f4-on-per-application-basis)

and modified my `rc.xml` thus:

```xml
    <keybind key="A-F4">
     <action name="If">
      <application class="URxvt"
        title="tmux-session">
      </application>
      <then><!-- Do nothing for urxvt-tmux-session --></then>
      <else>
       <action name="Close" />
      </else>
     </action>
    </keybind>
```

This works slightly better than before: I cannot <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> that terminal, but also cannot <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> any urxvt window now. (Guess this is because new urxvt windows are all run under the same class-name?)

Besides that I can kill everything I need from the menu bar, or right clicking into my tint panel, or, of course, by command.
But this approach means that:

1. I can still kill my drop-down terminal by right-clicking into the tint2 panel (maybe fixable if I make the drop-down terminal not appearing as an icon to the panel - should be possible with some research).
2. I cannot <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> other terminal windows (not liking it much, but maybe acceptable).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If switching to `xterm` is an option, you could use the hack below. There are a few caveats though. Once you address most of them, the solution ends up quite complicated, see the final script at the end.

```
xterm -e 'trap "" HUP; your-application'
```

Upon receiving the instruction to close from the window manager, `xterm` will send a SIGHUP to the process group of your-application, and only exit itself when the process returns.

That assumes your-application doesn't reset the handler for SIGHUP and could have unwanted side effects for the children of your-application.

Both of which seem to be a problem if  your-application is `tmux`.

To work around those, you could do:

```
xterm -e sh -c 'bash -mc tmux <&1 & trap "" HUP; wait'
```

That way, `tmux` would be started in a different process group, so only the `sh` would receive the SIGHUP (and ignore it).

Now, that doesn't apply to `tmux` which resets the handler for those signals anyway, but in the general case, depending on your implementation of `sh`, the SIGINT, SIGQUIT signals and generally both will be ignored for your-application as that `bash` is started as an asynchronous command from a non-interactive `sh`. That means you couldn't interrupt your-application with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+\</kbd>.

That's a POSIX requirement. Some shells like `mksh` don't honour it (at least not the current versions), or only in part like `dash` that does it for for SIGINT but not SIGQUIT. So, if `mksh` is available, you could do:

```
xterm -e mksh -c 'bash -mc your-application <&1 & trap "" HUP; wait'
```

(though that may not work in future versions of `mksh` if they decide to fix that non-conformance).

Or if you can't guarantee that `mksh` or `bash` will be available or would rather not rely on behaviour that may change in the future, you can do their work by hand with `perl` and for instance write an `unclosable-xterm` wrapper script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] || set -- "${SHELL:-/bin/sh}"
exec xterm -e perl -MPOSIX -e '
  $pid = fork;
  if ($pid == 0) {
    setpgrp or die "setpgrp: $!";
    tcsetpgrp(0,getpid) or die "tcsetpgrp: $!";
    exec @ARGV;
    die "exec: $!";
  }
  die "fork: $!" if $pid < 0;
  $SIG{HUP} = "IGNORE";
  waitpid(-1,WUNTRACED)' "$@"
```

(to be called as `unclosable-xterm your-application and its args`).

Now, another side effect is that that new process group we're creating and putting in foreground (with `bash -m` or `setpgrp`+`tcsetpgrp` above) is no longer the session leader process group, so no longer an *orphaned* process group (there's a parent supposedly caring for it now (`sh` or `perl`)).

What that means is that upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, that process will be suspended. Here, our careless parent will just exit, which means the process group will get a SIGHUP (and hopefully die).

To avoid it, we could just ignore the SIGTSTP in the child process, but then if your-application is an interactive shell, for some implementations like `mksh`, `yash` or `rc`, <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> won't work either for the jobs they run.

Or we could implement a more careful parent that resumes the child each time it's stopped, like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] || set -- "${SHELL:-/bin/sh}"
exec xterm -e perl -MPOSIX -e '
  $pid = fork;
  if ($pid == 0) {
    setpgrp or die "setpgrp: $!";
    tcsetpgrp(0,getpid) or die "tcsetpgrp: $!";
    exec @ARGV;
    die "exec: $!";
  }
  die "fork: $!" if $pid < 0;
  $SIG{HUP} = "IGNORE";
  while (waitpid(-1,WUNTRACED) > 0 && WIFSTOPPED(${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE})) {
    kill "CONT", -$pid;
  }' "$@"
```

Another issue is that if `xterm` is gone for another reason than the *close* from the window manager, for example if `xterm` is killed or loses the connection to the X server (because of `xkill`, the *destroy* action of you Window manager, or the X server crashes for instance), then those processes won't die as SIGHUP would also be used in those cases to terminate them. To work around that, you could use `poll()` on the terminal device (which would be torn down when `xterm` goes):

```
#! /bin/sh -
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] || set -- "${SHELL:-/bin/sh}"
exec xterm -e perl -w -MPOSIX -MIO::Poll -e '
  $pid = fork; # start the command in a child process
  if ($pid == 0) {
    setpgrp or die "setpgrp: $!"; # new process group
    tcsetpgrp(0,getpid) or die "tcsetpgrp: $!"; # in foreground
    exec @ARGV;
    die "exec: $!";
  }
  die "fork: $!" if $pid < 0;
  $SIG{HUP} = "IGNORE"; # ignore SIGHUP in the parent
  $SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    if (waitpid(-1,WUNTRACED) == $pid) {
      if (WIFSTOPPED(${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE})) {
        # resume the process when stopped
        # we may want to do that only for SIGTSTP though
        kill "CONT", -$pid;
      } else {
        # exit when the process dies
        exit;
      }
    }
  };

  # watch for terminal hang-up
  $p = IO::Poll->new;
  $p->mask(STDIN, POLLERR);
  while ($p->poll <= 0 || $p->events(STDIN) & POLLHUP == 0) {};
  kill "HUP", -$pid;
  ' "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think i should go that way though, (1) i'd have to config xterm to do what i want (not sure if possible) and more importantly, (2) there will be certainly many children from that app - i'm using it also as a launcher

Comment: @John, see edit for a solution that works with `tmux`. Note that `xterm` is a lot more configurable that `rxvt`.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has a somewhat misleading title, leading your research in the wrong direction. When you close a window in `X`, **the server doesn't kill your process**. Instead, it sends a `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` message to the process, which in turn terminates. This fact dooms your first approach: even if you set the `SIGNAL_UNKILLABLE` flag, you'll still be able to close it.

Your second approach seems usable, all you have to do is to discriminate a single terminal window against all others. One way to achieve that is to start `urxvt` with a particular title, for example `urxvt -name urxvt-iddqd`, and create a rule for its name:

```
<keybind key="A-F4">
 <action name="If">
  <application title="urxvt-iddqd"
    title="tmux-session">
  </application>
  <then><!-- Do nothing for urxvt-tmux-session --></then>
  <else>
   <action name="Close" />
  </else>
 </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, i think... also thanks for clarifying the problem with my initial approach. I will let the question run for a day though before accepting an answer

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I noticed the error already, thanks. Anyway, my understanding is that POSIX signals are not used, so approaches defeating SIGKILL won't help.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, yes, that's right, no POSIX signal involved between WM, X server and X client (terminal emulator here), but there could be between terminal emulator and application running within the terminal emulator (see my answer).

Comment: Dmitry, a minor nit with your answer is that you are using title twice in the code. Also i saw that by using urxvt -name myname, the .Xresources file was not read. Fixed the last by using urxvt -title myname

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided the following solution:

> I found a solution that works for me based on [Dmitry's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270679/423679) and my above edit:
>
> 1. I set a custom title to my `urxvt`:
>
> ```
> urxvt -title urxvt-drop-down
> ```
>
> I didn't use a custom name because it appears that the
>
> ```
> urxvt -name urxvt-drop-down
> ```
>
> command ignores the `.Xresources` file that i currently use, while `-title` uses it.
>
> 2. I made the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> keybind to ignore terminals titled `urxvt-drop-down`.
>    rc.xml:
>
> ```xml
>    <keybind key="A-F4">
>     <action name="If">
>      <title>urxvt-drop-down</title>
>      <then><!-- Do nothing for urxvt-drop-down --></then>
>      <else>
>       <action name="Close" />
>      </else>
>     </action>
>    </keybind>
> ```
>
> 3. I made the culprit never appear in the taskbar, and since the `skip_taskbar` also unfocuses the window, refocused it.
>    `rc.xml`:
>
> ```xml
>    <application title="urxvt-drop-down">
>      <skip_taskbar>yes</skip_taskbar>
>      <focus>yes</focus>
>    </application>
> ```
>
> Even though this solves the problem for me, it is essentially a workaround.
> Thus I'm not yet sure if [Stephane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270680/423679) is the correct one for this question.
>
> Need to do a little research on the commands presented to understand what's being done.
>
> I won't be using `xterm` though, since I want fake-transparency and drop-down capability (some kind of drop-down might be possible with xterm too I think, but transparency certainly ain't without a compositor - and I won't use a compositor).